# how to convert coordinate string list to tuple type in python

Tags: python, list

I want to convert list of coordinates in string to tuple without using external library

**type list**

`a = ['(1,4)', '(5,8)']`

Output

**type tuple**

`a = [(1,4), (5,8)]`

what i did

```
a = tuple(a)
```

**OUTPUT GETTING** ('(1,4)', '(5,8)')

**OUTPUT EXPECTED** ((1,4), (5,8))

Comment: from your code the output will be `('(1,4)', '(5,8)')`

Comment: yes  i want to remove ' ' from output @YashMehta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a super clean way to do this in general. However, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert individual elements to a tuple such as:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = ['(1,2)', '(3,4)']
output_tuple = tuple(literal_eval(x) for x in a)
```

You can find the documentation for `literal_eval` [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: i dont want to use external module @BTables

Comment: @amit [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) comes with python distributions by default.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it list like that and output with type tuple
you have 2 method

method 1:

```
a = ['(1,4)', '(5,8)']
a = tuple([eval(x) for x in a])

print(a)
```

method 2: (using internal library)

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = ['(1,4)', '(5,8)']
a = tuple([literal_eval(x) for x in a])
print(a)
```

Comment: Using `eval` should always be avoided in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
a = ['(1,4)', '(5,8)']
a = tuple([tuple(map(int, x[1:-1].split(','))) for x in a])

print(a)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).